# ReactiveCocoa countdown to date

Tags: objective-c, reactive-cocoa

Just starting out with ReactiveCocoa and slowly converting my current code to use it.

Right now i have a countdown to date timer done, just im not sure how to stop the timer when the countdown is done and do another action on complete.

```
NSTimeInterval dateInSecond = 1440855240;
self.dateUntilNextEvent = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:dateInSecond];
RACSignal *countdownSignal  = [[[[RACSignal interval:1 onScheduler:[RACScheduler schedulerWithPriority:RACSchedulerPriorityBackground]]
                                 startWith:[NSDate date]] map:^id(NSDate *value) {

    if([self.dateUntilNextEvent earlierDate:value] == self.dateUntilNextEvent){
        //Stop "timer" and call an onComeplete method
        return @"0";
    }

    NSUInteger flags = NSDayCalendarUnit
    | NSHourCalendarUnit
    | NSMinuteCalendarUnit
    | NSSecondCalendarUnit;

    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:flags
                                                                   fromDate:value
                                                                     toDate:self.dateUntilNextEvent options:0];

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02ld  :   %02ld   :  %02ld   :  %02ld",
            (long)[components day], (long)[components hour],
            (long)[components minute], (long)[components second]];

}] deliverOn:RACScheduler.mainThreadScheduler];

RAC(self.countdownLabel,text) = countdownSignal;
```

Any help would be appriciated, or just which direction to go in!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `-takeUntilBlock:` to shut down the signal when some predicate becomes true:

```
@weakify(self);
RAC(self.countdownLabel, text) =
  [[[[[RACSignal interval:1
           onScheduler:[RACScheduler schedulerWithPriority:RACSchedulerPriorityBackground]]
      startWith:[NSDate date]]
      takeUntilBlock:^BOOL(NSDate *date) {

        @strongify(self);
        return [self.dateUntilNextEvent compare:date] == NSOrderedAscending;

      }]
      map:^id(NSDate *date) {

        // Your NSCalendar/NSString transformation here.

      }]
      deliverOn:RACScheduler.mainThreadScheduler];
```

**Totally unrelated:**

You also mentioned you're just getting started with ReactiveCocoa. One of the gotchas for new users is when a signal is retained by an object, but the signal is composed of blocks that make strong references to that same object.

In your `-map`, you've got references to `self`. The block therefore will take ownership of `self` (increment its retain count), and then when the block is given to the signal, the signal takes ownership of the block, and then finally when you bind the signal to `self.countdownLabel`, your `self` takes ownership of the signal.

Therefore, note that in my `-takeUntilBlock` I've used the `@weakify/@strongify` technique. Be sure to read up on this, or you'll introduce retain cycles into your code.

Comment: Amazing, thanks for the help and for the retain cycle issue tip! :)